# Having trouble swapping out images using paintComponent

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am working on a game and I am attempting to use a different image that is 'highlighted' when close to the player. Right now I am attempting to draw different images in paintComponent in the player's superclass, whose code is below:

```
public void paintComponent ( Graphics g ) {

  if ( isBeingUsed() && img_hi != null )
     g.drawImage( img_hi, point.x, point.y, null );
  else if ( img != null )
     g.drawImage( img, point.x, point.y, null );
}
```

This paintComponent method is called from the class extending JPanel, and this code is below:

```
public void paintComponent ( Graphics g ) {
  super.paintComponent( g );

  if ( img != null )
     g.drawImage( img, -1100, -1000, null );

  if ( player != null )
     player.paintComponent( g );

  for ( int i = 0; i < dirtList.length; i++ ) {
     if ( dirtList[i] != null )
        dirtList[i].paintComponent( g );
  }

  repaint();
}
```

As it is right now, the highlighted image versions only appear on the screen, but I know from debugging that the regular image version is being drawn. I am really not sure where my error is coming from and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You code has some worrying issues, but without context, it's hard to know if they are actually issues or not - for example, you should never call `paintComponent` directly on any component, nor should you be calling `repaint` instead a `paintXxx` method

Comment: What context would be helpful? If you don't call paintComponent within the class extending JPanel, where are you supposed to call it? And what do you mean by a paintXxx method? Thank you for your response!

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - *"If you don't call paintComponent within the class extending JPanel, where are you supposed to call it?"* - You're not suppose to, that's part of the Swing APIs responsibility; *"And what do you mean by a paintXxx method?"* - there are 4 paint methods, which you can override, but you should never call `repaint` or modify the state of the UI from within any of them

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for a better understanding into how painting works in Swing